AutoDesk Forge Api: How can I change the default fileUnit from the IFC model
We consistently need to convert file units to millimeters. Our IFC files come from various sources, with most files already translated into millimeters, but occasionally some are in inches. As a result, when we use the Property Database (userfunction), we encounter discrepancies in display values—some are in millimeters, while others remain in inches.
Is it possible for the Property Database to always return the display value in millimeters? We discovered that the unit in the Property Database is solely the IFC file unit and can not be changed.
While there is a way to apply scaling when you call this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(document, node, { keepCurrentModels: false, applyScaling: 'mm' });, this only affects the size of the model in the viewer and not the underlying data.
One possible solution is to convert every single object inside the Property Database to the desired unit, but this approach is not favorable.

We can override the property display unit using the profile API.
const profileSettings = Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.clone(Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.AEC);
profileSettings.settings.displayUnits.current = 'ft'; //!<<< Change this value to the unit you want. If you don't know which value to be filled in, please check `profileSettings.settings.displayUnits.values`

const profile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(profileSettings);
viewer.setProfile(profile);

ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/profiles/
Here is the full sample code
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css"
    type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    #forgeViewer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #F0F8FF;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="apsViewer"></div>
  <script>
    async function loadMainViewAsync(viewer, urn, viewableId) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        async function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
          await doc.downloadAecModelData();

          let viewable = (viewableId ? doc.getRoot().findByGuid(viewableId) : doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry());
          let model = await viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, { keepCurrentModels: true });

          await viewer.waitForLoadDone();
          resolve(model);
        }

        function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
          reject(new Error('Failed fetching Forge manifest'));
        }

        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
      });
    }

    let accessToken = "eyJhb...Ye205zg"

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ env: 'AutodeskProduction', accessToken }, async function () {
      const config3d = {
        modelBrowserStartCollapsed: true,
        modelBrowserExcludeRoot: false,
      };

      let viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('apsViewer'), config3d);
      let startedCode = viewer.start();
      if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
      }

      const profileSettings = Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.clone(Autodesk.Viewing.ProfileSettings.AEC);
      profileSettings.settings.displayUnits.current = 'ft';

      const profile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(profileSettings);
      viewer.setProfile(profile);

      await loadMainViewAsync(viewer, 'urn:dXJuOm...lmYw');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>`


It is important to clarify that setting profileSettings.settings.displayUnits.current to a unit like 'ft' only affects display units within the viewer,
not
property database queries. According to Viewer API documentation, the property database, which stores metadata about model elements, operates independently of viewer settings. Queries to the property database will return values in the units used when the IFC model was created, regardless of the display unit settings in the viewer. We need to determine if it is possible to set the settings of the underlying data, not just the viewer.
